# What bitcoin wallets support bip32 extended public key export?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, bitcoin-wallet-app

I'm looking for a bitcoin wallet, that can export an extended public key. I want to put that key on a server, generate a chain of addresses and receive bitcoins, and be sure, that my bitcoins are safe on the server.

Currently I know, that only Electrum can export extended public keys. Could someone suggest other wallets, that are capable of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider to use a hardware wallet: https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet.
IMO all of the available hardware wallet do allow to export an xpub.

### But watch out (regardless of what wallet you are going to use)!

Even if you private keys are safe when you use public child key derivation, what happens if an attacker compromises your server and **replaces the xpub with a extended key controlled by the attacker**?

Be careful and read about "Server Hardening".
Also, if you run a VPS or dedicated root server, your server-center operator may have full access to you file-storage.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitcoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) can export the extended public key via Settings > Diagnostics > Show xpub.

The description of that option says:

> View the extended public key of your wallet, so it can be imported into other apps and services. Be careful: doing so will disclose your monetary privacy to that app.

Answer (score 0):

In copay, bitpay or bitcoin.com wallet you can go to settings > scroll down to bitcoin wallets and choose the wallet in question > scroll down to "more options" > wallet information and then at the bottom the xpub will be shown as copayer0.